# Print the variable-qualifier details

Tags: ios, objective-c, lldb

In this example -

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ...
    // Making a strong reference here 
    UIViewController *strongPointer = self;

    // Making a weak reference here
    UIViewController __weak *weakPointer = self;
    ...
}
```

When actually debugging the app, is there anyway I can print the variable-qualifer (`__weak`, `__strong`, `__unsafe_unretained` etc.) for a variable (especially a local var not a class property or something like that)?
I am able to only get the type name, nothing else.

Not able to get this from lldb -

```
(lldb) frame variable strongPointer
(MYViewController *) strongPointer = 0x00007fb1d7507b50
(lldb) frame variable weakPointer
(MYViewController *) weakPointer = 0x00007fb1d7507b50
(lldb) frame info strongPointer
frame #0: 0x000000010f7a366e MYSDKDemo`-[MYViewController viewDidLoad](self=0x00007fb1d7507b50, _cmd="viewDidLoad") at MYViewController.m:51
(lldb) frame info weakPointer
frame #0: 0x000000010f7a366e MYSDKDemo`-[MYViewController viewDidLoad](self=0x00007fb1d7507b50, _cmd="viewDidLoad") at MYViewController.m:51
(lldb)
```

I am also fine with this being printed when running the app.

Is there something available for this in `#import <objc/runtime.h>`?
Was not able to find anything over there as well.

Comment: The objc runtime doesn't barf up that kind of metadata.   It would have to be found by grubbing through the symbol tables, I think.  You could likely do code inspection to figure it out, but that's going to be rife with complexity and will change with nearly every compiler release.

In other words, no-- there isn't a reasonably easy way to do this.

Comment: This information is also not recorded in the debug information, and since this is a local variable there won't be any symbol for it.

Comment: Your best bet is to file a bug on the clang to include this decorator information in the debug info for objc types.

Comment: @JimIngham Ok, will do that, after some poking around. Thank you for the help :)